# Import functions from module to global namespace in Coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, module, coffeescript

Start with your module, utils.coffee:

```
exports.foo = ->
exports.bar = ->
```

Then your main file:

```
utils = require './utils'
utils.foo()
```

foo() and bar() are functions you'll be calling frequently, so you:

```
foo = require('./utils').foo
bar = require('./utils').bar
foo()
```

This approach works when only a few functions are defined in the module, but becomes messy as the number of functions increases. Is there a way to add all of a module's functions to your app's namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to add all of a module's functions to your app's namespace?

No. This is, to my knowledge, the best you can do (using CS' [destructuring assignment](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#destructuring)):

```
{foo, bar, baz} = require('./utils')
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `extend` (with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or any other library that provides it. Write it yourself if necessary):

```
_(global).extend(require('./utils'))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use underscore, you could simply do:

```
var utils = require('./utils')
for (var key in utils)
  global[key] = utils[key]
```

Comment: Not bad! I wish Coffeescript had an equivalent to the Python one-liner "import * from bar".

Comment: @knife it's one line, though not a one liner: global[k] = v for k,v of require './utils'

Answer (score 1):

Another way to exports all modules function to global scope like so:
Application Module:

```
(()->
    Application = @Application = () ->
        if @ instenceof Application
            console.log "CONSTRUCTOR INIT"
    Application::test = () ->
        "TEST"

    Version = @Version = '0.0.0.1'
)()
```

Main App:

```
require  './Application'

App = new Appication()
console.log App.test()
console.log Version
```

Comment: Interesting idea! I'm going to try this for a bit before marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
global[k] = v for k,v of require './utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that is a good approach to my opinion:

utils.coffee

```
module.exports = 
    foo: ->
        "foo"
    bar: ->
        "bar"
```

main.coffee

```
util = require "./util"
console.log util.foo()
```

Comment: I think the OP asked for a way to _import_ all functions from a module, not how to _export_ all functions in a module. The advice is useful, though.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I've added another Answer below :)